# Writing into an external file with streamlit

Tags: python, machine-learning, streamlit

I am currently working on a ML project using streamlit in the "streamlit cloud".

For model fitting, no problem, I can do it independent of streamlit and store the trained model in a pickle file. After that, the pickle file is added to the streamlit project. For several reasons, I have to write into a file inside the streamlit app.

After searching the web and here, I don't get a good answer. Maybe, writing into a file is impossible with streamlit. In this case I may look to Heroku but as a newbie, I prefer streamlit!

What do you think?

I saw the following code here, but it doesn't work for me:

```
b0 = st.button("Hi There", key=0)
if b0:
    st.write("gratitude word")
    with open("file.csv", "w") as f:
        print("xxx", file=f)
```

Comment: Writing and reading is a big difference when you are in the cloud. When cloud is free, usually you are not allowed to write. But there are solutions to your problem. I tried deta, it is free. You can save files and database in deta. You can use streamlit to access deta.

Comment: You can write a file in your app hosted on Streamlit Cloud but the complexity is in retrieving that file, since the app lives in a container, and you don't get access to that container's file directory. You could do the opposite and have your app enable you to download that file (e.g., using st.download_button), would that work?

Comment: OP, you can write files to the local session in streamlit cloud, but they’ll be lost when the user starts a new session i.e. if they lose their connection or close and reopen the browser. To use streamlit this way, an algorithm I use is write-back; take the user input data or file, write to cloud storage, then retrieve for local session caching and processing. Then store the user state of objects in cloud alongside data.

Answer (score 1):

To add a file to your app programmatically, you'll want to use the [GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents) since Streamlit Community Cloud pulls your app from a GitHub repository.